# Unwarping image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, unwarp

[image]

I am trying to unwarp seggregated views taken from an OV5647 (RPi) camera with Fisheye lens. I have tried calibrating the camera using the code in the https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camera-calibration-with-opencv-f324679c6eb7. I have also tried several other codes but of no avail. Is there any alternate way to unwarp the sample image shown, as it appears to be folded across a single vertical axis about middle of the image.

Apart from several codes generated by ChatGPT i have tried the following codes but haven't gotten satisfactory results:
https://github.com/jeeho-ahn/OpenCV_Camera_Calibration_Undistort_Video
https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/camera-calibration-with-opencv-f324679c6eb7
https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/calibrate-fisheye-lens-using-opencv-333b05afa0b0

Comment: Your links look like several quite detailed explanations of how to do it with code provided. Maybe you should just try from the beginning. What else can there be in an answer better than what you already have? I don't think you will get an answer as long and as detail as the links you provided yourself.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).